# Why do you need to put list() when appending a list to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the coding problem I'm doing right now in Python3:

```
class TreeNode:
  def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
    self.val = val
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

def find_paths(root, targetSum):
  allPaths = []
  dfs(root, targetSum, [], allPaths)
  return allPaths
  
def dfs(node, targetSum, currentPath, result):
  
  if not node:
    return
  
  currentPath.append(node.val)

  if node.val == targetSum:
    if not node.left and not node.right:
      result.append(list(currentPath))
  else:
    dfs(node.left, targetSum - node.val, currentPath, result)
    dfs(node.right, targetSum - node.val, currentPath, result)

  # backtrack here
  del currentPath[-1]


def main():

  root = TreeNode(12)
  root.left = TreeNode(7)
  root.right = TreeNode(1)
  root.left.left = TreeNode(4)
  root.right.left = TreeNode(10)
  root.right.right = TreeNode(5)
  required_sum = 23
  print(find_paths(root, required_sum))


main()
```

The question is this line right here:

```
      result.append(list(currentPath))
```

it prints out:

```
[[12, 7, 4], [12, 1, 10]]
```

but if you put:

```
      result.append(currentPath)
```

it will print out:

```
[[], []]
```

I tried printing out the type of "currentPath" and it is already a list. Why is the list() necessary when it's already of type list?

Comment: It's to make a shallow copy.

Comment: that makes perfect sense! thank you

Answer (score 3):

Because of this:

```
del currentPath[-1]
```

In other words: you are adding the `currentPath` object to your result object, but then you later modify it. The modification is reflected in your `result`. Using `list(…)` makes a *copy* of the list.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, if you do

```py
result.append(currentPath)
```

then you appending the object `currentPath`. This, effectively, you can think of it as appending a pointer to the object `currentPath`. Meaning that the `result` will actually hold the `currentPath` and not the contents of the `currentPath`.

Thus, when you will do

```py
del currentPath[-1]
```

you will alter the `currentPath` object. Since the `result` has the actual `currentPath`, then the `result` will also be modified.

BUT!

When you are doing

```py
result.append(list(currentPath))
```

you are appending a new object, having the contents of the `currentPath`. This results to `result` having a different object in it, and not the actual `currentPath`. This is because the `list()` will create a new list, from the contents of the `currentPath`.

Thus, when you are modifying the contents of the `currentPath` with the

```py
del currentPath[-1]
```

the `result` will not be modified.

---

To verify it your self, you can check the

```py
id(result[0])
id(currentPath)
```

when using the `.append(list(currentPath))` and when using the `.append(currentPath)`.